# CXF @XmlElement(required=true) not working

Tags: java, soap, jaxb, xsd, cxf

I have the following interface:

```
    @WebMethod(action = "create")
VoidResponse create(    
                                @WebParam(name="description") @XmlElement(required=true) String description, 
                                @WebParam(name="userId") @XmlElement(required=true) String userId, 
                                @WebParam(name="accountImage") String accountImage...);
```

and this is the wsdl complex type generated:

```
<xs:complexType name="create">
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element name="description" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:element name="userId" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="accountImage" type="xs:string"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

As we can see, the description and userId are required fields.
It seems to be correct, but, when I make a request, omitting the description field, or sending it empty, for example, the CXF doesn't throw a soapFault.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you add your import statement for @XmlElement? Maybe this is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default cxf do not perform schema validations. You need to enable it manually by adding below settings to your web service interface

```
@WebService(name = "abc", targetNamespace = "xyz", wsdlLocation="/path to wsdl")
@EndpointProperties(value = {
    @EndpointProperty(key="schema-validation-enabled", value="true")
})
public interface MyFirstSOAPWebService{
    @WebMethod(action = "create")
    VoidResponse create(    
                            @WebParam(name="description") @XmlElement(required=true) String description, 
                            @WebParam(name="userId") @XmlElement(required=true) String userId, 
                            @WebParam(name="accountImage") String accountImage...);
}
```

> Please note: **wsdlLocation** setting is mandatory, along with **schema-validation-enabled** because cxf needs to know the xsds to validate the incoming requests. wsdl location will provide the required xsds

Answer (score 0):

Can you try setting up schema validation on your jaxws:endpoint definition? Something like below if you are using Spring

`<jaxws:endpoint ...>
        <jaxws:properties>
            <entry key="schema-validation-enabled" value="true" />
        </jaxws:properties>
...
    </jaxws:endpoint>`

or even annotating your Service with `@org.apache.cxf.annotations.SchemaValidation`